# recognize_google fails with WinError 10060

Tags: python, connection, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm encountering a **TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]** while attempting to establish a connection in my Python program. This error arises when the connected party does not respond properly within a specific time frame, or when the established connection fails due to the connected host not responding. I think that recognize_google has something with it, because the program stops at this point:
`text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)`

**Code Sample:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
    
    # Initialize the recognizer
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    
    # Capture audio from the microphone
   
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Speak something...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    
        try:
            # Use the recognizer to convert speech to text
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print("You said:", text)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry, could not understand audio.")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

**Error Message:**

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

**Additional Context:**
Python Version: 3.7
PyAudio: 0.2.11
playsound: 1.2.2